# not able to create constructor of model class and getting object reference not set to instance of object error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

this is my Model:

```
public class UserDetails
{
            public string UserName { get; set; }
            public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

this is my query to fetch user details along with category:

```
var data = (from temp in context.UserDetails.Include("Category") select temp).OrderBy(c => c.UserId);
```

this is how i am accessing on controller:

```
List<UserDetails> staffDetails = staffBal.fetchStaffDetails();
      var categoryModel = new CategoryModel();
                Data = staffDetails.Select(x =>
                {
                    var userDetailModel = new UserDetailsModel();
                      userDetailModel.UserId = x.UserId;
                    userDetailModel.FName = x.FName;
   categoryModel.CategoryName = x.Category.Name;//i am getting error on this line.object reference not set to instance of object
```

can anybody tell me what is the solution???

Comment: `x.Category` is null?

Comment: for some records it is coming null for some records it is not null

Comment: Then `categoryModel` is null.

Comment: no categorymodel is not null

Comment: In ``Category.Name`` ``Category`` or ``Category.Name`` is null

Comment: can u tell me how initiallize class category thorugh constrcutor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say in your comment: `for some records it is coming null for some records it is not null` meaning that `x.Category` is null. Therefore, any attempt to access `x.Category.Name` will fail. Change the line to this:

```
categoryModel.CategoryName = x.Category == null ? "" : x.Category.Name;
```

Comment: Depends on the question!

Comment: var data = (from temp in context.UserDetails.Include("Category")
                           select
                               new UserDetails
                               {
                                   FName = temp.FName + " " + temp.LName,
                                   EmailId = temp.EmailId,
                                   UserName = temp.UserName
                               }).OrderBy(c => c.UserId);

Comment: for this query can u tell me how do i get category name